# Use a name for Facebook Page, that was used for regular profile before

Tags: facebook-pages, username

When I first registered a Facebook account in 2008, I did not understand about Pages. But in a misguided attempt to "reserve" my website name, `happiocracy.com`, I used it as my personal user name. So I got a nice URL, `www.facebook.com/happiocracy`.

But I now want to use this URL for my Facebook Page that is about happiocracy.

I know that Facebook doesn't allow transfers to another account, but in this case, the transfer would be to a different Page in the same account. I was thinking of changing my personal User name but I'm afraid that it will then become unavailable even to me. I'm wondering if I can simply use my present personal page for my website and open a "new" page for myself.

But in this case I shall lose all my personal contacts. This would be a nuisance but not an insurmountable problem. But the easiest way would simply be to transfer "my" URL to a Paqe. Any bright suggestions that will not fall foul of Facebook's rules?

Answer (score 1):

From what I have read around the internet is that:

- Facebook allows you to change your profile username **once** but
  Facebook pages are given no such chance. So change your Facebook
  profile username to something else. Once you are done with that, you
  wait for Facebook to release your username [this can be around 2-3
  days to 2 weeks]. Keep checking everyday if the username is
  available, and once it is, snag it.
- The second option is to contact them through [this form](http://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=username_infringement) and explain
  your position. Hopefully, they should get back to you with your
  desired username for the page.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not realize that they release names. I seem to remember reading somewhere that once a name has been given up, they block it from further use to prevent squatting. I also didn't know about the form. I will certainly try that. Thanks again. Much appreciated

Comment: No problem. Hope it works out for you.

Comment: If I'm not missing something, you're now (beginning of 2014) able to change your name up to **four** times, not once. Of course -- as Tony said -- this, again, is possible only on personal profiles, not Pages.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.facebook.com/help/516060455143473

> How do I transfer my username from my profile to my Page?
>
> You can only transfer your username once. To transfer your username from your profile to your Page:
>
> 1. Click Settings at the top of your Page
> 2. Click Page Info in the left column
> 3. Click Facebook Web Address and click Change web address
> 4. Enter the username assigned to your profile and click Check Availability
> 5. Click Transfer Username
>
> Once you've transferred your username to your Page, you won't be able to transfer it again. Keep in mind that you'll need to be an admin of the Page to transfer your username.
>
> Note: At this time, you can't transfer your Page's username to your profile.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://www.facebook.com/username and type your profile username ( happiocracy ) as your page username. Facebook will then ask you to confirm that you want to transfer your profile username to your page username.

Comment: Have you tested this?

Comment: Yes, and it worked.